# stop bubbling event onclick

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-4, event-bubbling

I have the following

```html
<p>haha</p>
<button class="btn btn-light" onclick="nextSibling.classList.toggle('d-none');">
  <i class="fa fa-ellipsis-h"></i>
</button>
<div class="prev-content d-none">
  <p>second reply from second account</p>
  <br>
  <button class="btn btn-light" onclick="nextSibling.classList.toggle('d-none');">
    <i class="fa fa-ellipsis-h"></i>
  </button>
  <div class="prev-content d-none">
    <p>reply from system</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

I want to show only next sibling `<div class="prev-content">` by click on button, but there is some strange behavior. It shows all divs or it hides all divs. I think the reason in bubbling events.

How can I resolve that?

Comment: PS: you should always, by muscle memory add `type="button"` to all buttons that are not of type *submit*.

Comment: Also, your example produces *"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'toggle' of undefined"*

Comment: For starters, you should be using `nextElementSibling` instead of `nextSibling` – because the latter is likely to refer to a whitespace _text_ node between the elements, in certain browsers.

Comment: _“I think the reason in bubbling events.”_ - even when the event bubbles up from those button elements, neither of them has any ancestor element that reacts to a click event. So how could bubbling be responsible then?

Comment: Works fine with `nextElementSibling`, see https://jsfiddle.net/2dg64qzn/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Don't use inline JS same as you don't use inline `style` attributes
- Use [addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener)
- Use [Event.currentTarget](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/currentTarget) inside the function handler to refer to the event delegated Element
- Use [nextElementSibling](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/nextElementSibling)
- Use finally [classList.toggle](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) to toggle a specific class

```js
const toggleNext = (ev) => {
  const EL = ev.currentTarget;
  const EL_next = EL.nextElementSibling;
  EL_next.classList.toggle("u-none");
};
const ELs_tog = document.querySelectorAll("[data-toggle-next]");
ELs_tog.forEach(EL => EL.addEventListener("click", toggleNext));
```

```css
.u-none {display: none;}
```

```html
<button type="button" data-toggle-next>TOGGLE</button>
<div class="u-none">
  <p>second reply from second account</p>
  <button type="button" data-toggle-next>TOGGLE</button>
  <div class="u-none">
    <p>reply from system</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Additional read:

- [Node.nodeType](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/nodeType)